# Convert \xc3\xd8\xe8\xa7\xc3\xb4\xd to human readable format

Tags: python-2.7, thai

I am having trouble converting '\xc3\xd8\xe8\xa7\xc3\xb4\xd' (which is a Thai text) to a readable format. I get this value from a smart card, and it basically was working for Windows but not in Linux.

If I print in my Python console, I get:

```
����ô
```

I tried to follow some google hints but I am unable to accomplish my goal.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your text does not seem to be a Unicode text. Instead, it looks like it is in one of Thai encodings. Hence, you **must** know the encoding before printing the text.

For example, if we assume your data is encoded in **TIS-620** (and the last character is `\xd2` instead of `\xd`) then it will be "รุ่งรดา".

To work with the non-Unicode strings in Python, you may try: `myString.decode("tis-620")` or even `sys.setdefaultencoding("tis-620")`

Comment: I did solve my issue using my String. Drcode ("tis-620"). Need to dig in detail about these encodings.